# Network Drives disconnecting, account currently disables

Tags: windows-7, network-shares, windows-server-2008-r2, active-directory

User machine is Windows 7 32bit, server is 2K8R2.

I have a user who will have her network drives disconnected (big red x). Double clicking them gives:
[image: imgur]

Locking/unlocking will work at times, restarting helps for a while, but resetting her password and ticking "unlock this account" will fix it for a day or two. It seems like her account is being locked out, but she is still able to log into her PC, and others that don't have her credentials cached. Outlook connects to exchange without problem.

I have looked for her account as a service to no avail, and I've tried using Lockout Fixer and similar other tools.

Any help finding what is locking her account, if that's what's happening, or other suggestions for things to try?

Comment: Pic link broken.

Comment: Fixed it as you were commenting.

Comment: If you manually map a drive using her own credentials do you get the same probelem? Reason I ask is that you may be mapping the drives with differing credentials than her own.

Comment: Also, how are these drives mapped? login script? GPO?

Comment: Typically with GPO. I've troubleshooted by mapping manually, and she still gets the error. I manually map with her credentials.

Comment: One more Q, just to be clear. is it just THIS MACHINE that is having the problem? or does she experience the same issues on other machines. Also, I assume her account is the only one with this issue?

Comment: It happens on other machines. I bought her a new PC to try and fix the issue, but it still continues. She is the only user having this problem.

Answer (score 1):

Okay try this, from what you have told me it seems like something in that particular account's credentialing or settings is blocking this from happening. this can occur occasionally from time to time especially on older accounts.

Back up all her profiles and data, delete her AD account, replicate to your other DCs, create another account (use a different Username just to be sure) and set her up again. You don't have to delete her Exchange box. Just reconnect it to the new account.

It's a pain in the ass, I know, but it would work.

Comment: Small price to pay, but will this cause outlooks auto complete to fail when users send her an email? In other words, create new account connect to old exchange box, change primary email to previous account name. Because this is a new account will autocomplete fail?

Comment: Yeah it will cause some weirdness with autocompletes since those are locally cached on each machine. hopefully, if people are using the Global Address Book to reach her, that will only cause weirdness until the GAB refreshes in 48 hours. If not, just inform users who report problems to type the email address in manually. that will add the new settings to their autocomplete lists.